# How to create global static method in JS

Tags: javascript, static, global

I am trying to create a global method that can be called from any object. For example, I want to call `random()` from myObject.x:

```
function random() {
    this = 22;
}

const myObject = {
    x: 0,
}

Object.prototype.random = random;

myObject.x.random();
console.log(myObject.x);
```

EDIT: 
Suggestion by Touffy is very close, here's modified version:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'random', {
    value: function() {
        return 22;
    },
    enumerable: false // this is by default, you don't need to write it actually
})

const myObject = {
    x: 0,
}

console.log(myObject.x); // 0
myObject.x.random(); // Updates x to 22
console.log(myObject.x); // Should be 22
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit risky? especially if you will be using your code with other third party libraries. I think this should be avoided.

Comment: It's not static, what you describe is an instance method. As shanks said, it's bad practice to extend Object.prototype (even with `enumerable: false`), but until we get the binding operator (::) it seems like the only option.

Comment: also, `this = 22` won't work. What are you trying to do??

Comment: I am trying to build a method that can be used the same way as `toString()` for example. I am not planning to use this solution in production, it's more of a quiz question

Comment: toString() returns a value but does not change `this`. You can easily write a method that returns a random number, except of course if it does not depend on `this`, there's no point making it a method, just use Math.random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is almost perfect. The problem is with `this = 22`. You can't modify the `this` value and you need to call the `random` method on the `myObject` not on the `myObject.x`.

Try this:

```js
function random(propertyName) {
    this[propertyName] = 22;
}
    
const myObject = {
    x: 0,
}
    
Object.prototype.random = random;
    
myObject.random('myRandomNumber');
console.log(myObject.myRandomNumber);
```

I think this is not so proper solution. You should use a lib like [ChanceJS](http://chancejs.com/) (or you can code your own). In this case you don't need to add `random` function to the Object's prototype.

```
// Load Chance
var Chance = require('chance');

// Instantiate Chance so it can be used
var chance = new Chance();

const myObject = {
    x: 0,
}

myObject.x = chance.integer();
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for because in this case you can apply random() method only to objects that contain x object

Comment: Almost :) But still not what I am looking for. I want this method to be applied directly on object which calls the method, so I want to be able to call it directly from `myObject.x` instead of calling from `myObject` and passing `x` as an argument

Comment: so I need both versions to work: `myObject.x.random()`, `mySecondObject.something.a.random()`

Comment: using kotapeter's solution, you can achieve that by doing `mySecondObject.something.random('a')`

Comment: As @shanks mentioned this is not the best way to generate a random number. Better solution is to write your own random-number generator or use a lib and you can assign the random number to your object's property.

Comment: Sorry for leading you to a wrong direction. I wanted to know is it possible to call a method directly from object whose value would be changed by this method. `random()` was used here just for purpose of example

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the motivation for doing this, you should at least make your global method non enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'random', {
    value: function(property) {
        this[property] = 22
    },
    enumerable: false // this is by default, you don't need to write it actually
})
```

The reason for doing that is to prevent `for… in`, which is often used on basic Objects, from including your method in its iteration and confusing libraries that don't expect a "random" property on every object.

If you are patient or use a recent Babel, you can take advantage of the [bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator):

```
function random(property) {
    this[property] = 22
}

myObject::random('x')
// equivalent to:
random.call(myObject, 'x');
```

(edited to actually do something, using kotapeter's idea of passing the property name)

Comment: This doesn't change the value of object, it returns new value. Please see my updated question

Comment: YOU CANNOT assign to `this`. Use kotapeter's idea of passing the property name if you want to change the property's value.

Comment: So there is no way to change the value of the object which called the function?

Comment: Sorry, no. Not with a primitive value. `this` will always reference the same object inside a method call.